# Multiple wires in lighting fixtures

Tags: wiring, lighting

Took a light fixture down to replace it. We used the same wires that were previously used but new light won't come on. There are 3 black, 3 white and 1 green, 2 of the black and white are taped off and were not being used. There are 2 switches that can control the fixture. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Taking pictures before undoing wires always help.  It is possible since you said taped and not wire nuts/connectors, that the tape connections came loose(breaking the circuit).  If it is tape, get some wire nuts/connectors and do the wires up right.

Comment: If the previous fixture worked as wired, either the new one is not actually connected the same way, or something else was disturbed/disconnected when swapping fixtures. Check everything very carefully, it's almost never an ancient curse, and almost always an *oops!*

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all boxes involved please?

Answer (score -1):

The answer depends on where the multiple wires come from.

**Multiple wires coming from the fixture**

If the multiple wires are all coming from the fixture itself, then what they've done is simply pulled all the connections from the multiple lampholders back to one place.  There will be as many black (hot) wires as there are lampholders, the same number of white (neutral) wires, and usually  one ground wire for the fixture.

Hooking these up is easy.  Tie all the hots together with the incoming switched hot (generally black), tie all the neutrals together with the incoming neutral (generally white), and tie the ground to the incoming ground.

**Multiple wires coming from the ceiling/wall box**

Multiple wires in the box presents a different challenge.  There can be many permutations of switched hot, constant hot, and feeder cables for other lights that are controlled from that switch.  This is why it's important to make sure you understand where everything connects before removing the existing light fixture.

That is one we'll kind of have to test case by case, with pictures if possible.